# XQuery- will a single file or multiple files would be good in any XML DB

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db, basex

I am having an huge XML file containing the Resumes. This file is in two format viz-
A single master file containing all the Resumes for ex-

```
<Resumes>
  <Resume>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    ......
    ......
  </Resume>
  <Resume>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    ......
    ......
  </Resume>
  ......
  ......
</Resumes>
```

and multiple files for ex-

file 1-

```
<Resumes>
  <Resume>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    ......
    ......
  </Resume>
</Resumes>
```

file-2

```
<Resumes>
  <Resume>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    ......
    ......
  </Resume>
</Resumes>
```

and so on.

I want to use `baseX` or `eXist` XML DB for storing the XML. So in future, if I want to
**add more** Resumes (in XML) format then which one will be better?

Comment: I've heard that there are some XML Databases that cope well with data in a single huge document, but I think that for most products, many small documents works much better.

Comment: @MichaelKay- Yes. Right said. Still waiting for more expert views. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For eXist-db, let me quote from [a post on exist-open by Wolfgang Meier](http://exist-open.markmail.org/thread/byuzpoj7cyfmlqdo) in response to a similar question:

> I don't think there's a theoretical limit, but there are certainly
>   some **practical considerations**. Storing a very large document can block
>   the db more than storing many small ones. It requires a single
>   transaction (and sufficient disk space for the transaction log).
>
> The dblp bibliography, which I use for some automated performance
>   tests, comes as a single document with more than 600mb. This loads
>   well if you slightly increase the cache size and memory settings. I
>   know other users have to deal with much larger documents (many
>   gigabytes), **but if you have a choice, I would definitely recommend to
>   split your data in smaller chunks, which are easier to handle.**

Granted, eXist-db has become even more efficient and robust since November 2009 when Wolfgang wrote this post, but I think his advice still applies.  Two final notes:

1. Make sure you use the latest version of eXist, e.g. either [1.4.2](http://atomic.exist-db.org/blogs/eXist/Release142) or the [2.0 Tech Preview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exist/files/Stable/2.0/).  These benefit from the advances I spoke about.
2. To squeeze out the most performance of eXist-db, read the eXist-db documentation article entitled, [Performance Tuning](http://exist-db.org/exist/tuning.xml).

Comment: @joewiz- Thanks a lot :) Very good information shared by you... Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @John Sure thing!  I'd also encourage you to join the [exist-open mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open) - it's a good place to ask more detailed questions, stay abreast of current best practices, report your experience, etc.